# validate file type extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to prevent exe file upload in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your favorite answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to prevent users uploading dangerous content, preventing them to upload exe files isn't enough. This is a black list approach. Much better is to ask yourself what are the valid file types you do support and block all others. This is a white list.

To allow certain file types you can check for the extension, but perhaps also validate the file header (the first couple of bytes from a file) to detect whether it is actually of the  type you expect. You will have to figure out for each file type what the possible headers are.

Good luck.

Comment: The `Request.Files` property has a collection of `HttpPostedFileBase` instances. `HttpPostedFileBase` contains a `FileName` property that you can use. `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(string)` allows you to fetch the extension of a file.